# How to get objectId of user in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am currently working on a user registration setup. In the user model, I have defined apiKey as a property of the user and I want to set it equal to the user object Id. How can I do this ? Here is my code for the model :

```
const userScheama = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    email: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
      lowercase: true
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true
    },
    hashed_password: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    apiKey:{
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    plan:{
      type: String,
      required: false
    },
    salt: String,
    role: {
      type: String,
      default: 'subscriber'
    },
    resetPasswordLink: {
      data: String,
      default: ''
    }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mongoose hooks here. First you need to update your apiKey to `apiKey: {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId required: false },` and then add the below code to your model file

```
userScheama.pre('save', async function (next) {
  this.apiKey = this._id;
  next();
});
```

Comment: And one question , if a user registers to my app, then the API key is automatically generated as it is the object Id , so should I remove thew required: false and make it true ???